# Making a query with several JOINS

Tags: mysql, sql

I am stuck with some SQL query.

I have four tables. Which are connected:

**user** =>**user_account**=>**acount_profile_entries**=>**profile_entries**

From left to right they are one to many.

**user_account** has a user_id field as FK.
**account_profile_field** has **user_account_id** and **profile_entry_id**.
Profile_entries has a text field that I need to show for each user (account).

I need to write a query that will show me, all accounts for every user, and its profile entries.

I am sorry if this is confusing, I tried to make it simple

This is what I have done so far. I can show all accounts for every user and this is the point I am stuck with. Last two commented out Joins are not working properly. I believe I am close somewhat, I just need a push :)

```
SELECT
u.email AS Email,
u.id AS UserId,
ua.id AS UserAccountId,
ua.app_id AS Application
FROM users AS u
INNER JOIN user_accounts ua ON ua.user_id = u.id
-- INNER JOIN account_profile_entries ape ON ape.user_account_id = ua.id
-- INNER JOIN profile_entries as pe ON pe.id = ape.profile_entry_id
limit 10
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: The other tow joins are not working at all. They don't error out, just nothing is fetched from DB, I mean no values are coming from profile_entries. I made a small dataset in DB, that has all values inserted.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @VedranMaricevic. do you mean that the query including the commented joins returns the expected data but with empty profile_entries ?

Comment: Yes. That is correct. My query was returning empty values (nulls). I dont have DB near me to test these new ideas I got here. But

Comment: Then may be your profile_entries just have empty entries for each profile and your query is working as expected, either way, you should check the data of profile_entries  table by making just a simple SELECT query from profile_entries. and if not all users have accounts or profiles then you should do a left join as mentioned in @Aman Kumar's answer

Comment: It may be so. I will check asap.

Comment: Your query works like charm. I modified it slightly to include and exclude some fields. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Try this SQL Query with using [LEFT JOIN](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/advance-query-in-mysql/left-join.php)

**Description :-**  The MySQL LEFT JOIN joins two tables and fetches rows based on a condition, which is matching in both the tables and the unmatched rows will also be available from the table written before the JOIN clause.

> SYNTAX

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name;
```

[image]

```
SELECT u.*,
u.id AS UserId,
ua.id AS UserAccountId,
ua.app_id AS Application,pe.* FROM `users` u 
LEFT JOIN user_accounts ua ON ua.user_id = u.id 
LEFT JOIN account_profile_entries ape ON ape.user_account_id = ua.id
LEFT JOIN profile_entries as pe ON pe.id = ape.profile_entry_id LIMIT 10
```